# sharing socket descriptor between multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, select, network-programming

Just a quick question. I have a network C application (TCP server) which has multiple worker threads(Pthreads).Each worker thread uses a `select` system call and each thread has the listening `socket descriptor` added to its select set. So effectively each worker thread listens for incoming connections, and only one thread at a time succeeds in accepting the particular connection and that connection's `socket descriptor` is added to the respective thread's `select` set.

My question is that each thread has its own `select` set, is it possible that I can send or receive data to a client whose socket descriptor is in another worker threads select set ? in other words can I use a socket descriptor from any worker thread's select set to perform I/O from any thread I want?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share sockets and file descriptors between different threads. That's what most servers do.

Comment: Sorry for double checking:/ This means that if a thread accepts a connection and the returned file descriptor is added to other threads select set they will all be able to write/read from that descriptor right?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, it should make no difference in which thread the FD was created / accepted.

Comment: @Abdullah It is ok to use same sockets in different threads however you should probably make sure that read/write socket from one thread at time to avoid possible interleaving of data.

Comment: @MByD - it means threads can share file descriptors but process cannot,right ?